# ACTION_MOVE not firing consistently for a touch point held stationary on the screen. No historical events are batched. (Samsung Galaxy S)

Tags: android, touch

I am relying on `ACTION_MOVE` to provide a **constant** stream of events to my `TouchListener` which I've attached to a `GLSurfaceView`. Even if the user is holding their finger stationary, I'd still like to get `ACTION_MOVE` events - or some sort of `ACTION_*` event - at the location of the finger.

The problem is, I don't get a consistent stream of `ACTION_MOVE` events when a finger is held down.

Note, this is an issue **specifically when a finger is being held down** in a stationary manner. if the finger is moving around rather than being still, the `ACTION_MOVE` events are actually fired consistently.

Below are the logs I've collected.

When the hold starts, the touch events come in fairly regularly. (Note, in the logs below X is the number of historical events in `ACTION_MOVE: X`, and it is always 0).

```
25.374: E/InputSystem(7848): ACTION_DOWN
25.709: E/InputSystem(7848): ACTION_MOVE: 0    +35ms
25.874: E/InputSystem(7848): ACTION_MOVE: 0    +165ms - not great, but usable.
25.991: E/InputSystem(7848): ACTION_MOVE: 0    +127ms - not great, but usable. 
26.010: E/InputSystem(7848): ACTION_MOVE: 0    +29ms
```

If the finger continues to be held down, the situation worsens. The move events will start to take more than 1 second to fire. That is unacceptable for my application...

```
28.284: E/InputSystem(7848): ACTION_MOVE: 0
29.811: E/InputSystem(7848): ACTION_MOVE: 0 +1,527ms - NOPE!
```

Why is this happening?

We can rule out touch event batching since the history size is 0. Apart from a hardware issue, I don't know what to do about this! Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's working as expected.  The event is called ACTION_MOVE because it tells you that at least 1 pointer has moved.  If nothing has moved, there's no reason for it to be sent.  If you're depending on being sent a constant stream of these you need to redesign your application-  that should only happen if an actual move has occurred.

Comment: I see your point. I have an alternative design that works without the user having to hold their finger on the screen, but honestly, being able to hold the finger, even when the finger itself is stationary, is a much more natural way for the user to interact with my application... Hence I'd like to see some sort of events bubbled up from the touch driver (surely those events exist somewhere in Android input stack...) Luckily for me, the user should be moving their finger quite frequently, so this stationary case is a lesser priority... If this `ACTON_MOVE` behavior is by design then oh well!